# How to use WildFly maven plugin to deploy WAR to a remote WildFly?

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly, remote-server

I want to deploy a WAR to a remote WildFly server with WildfFly Maven plugin. I have configured my project with the right WildFly maven parameters. (hostname, portname, username, password).
But when I run mvn wildfly:deploy command, I got the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.1.0.Beta1:deploy (default-cli) on project opapp: Failed to execute goal deploy.: org.jboss.remoting3.ServiceOpenException: Unknown service name management
```

Please help, how can I fix it?

Comment: is you server management interface bound to 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: What does your configuration look like?

Comment: Please share the full definition on the plugin and is there a reason you are using a beta version of the plugin rather than a stable release?

Comment: thanks guys, I have solved it! In the configraution I used a wrong port